# Vue2-slider dot position

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Struggling with [vue2-slider](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component) dot. 
You can see that dot is in the start position and its center places on the left side of the progress bar:
https://jsfiddle.net/2xy72dod/469/

It's because of dot's `translateX(-14px)`.
I think translate value calculates on line 666 of vue2-silder.vue file:

```
let translateValue =
        this.direction === 'vertical'
          ? `translateY(${value}px)`
          : `translateX(${value}px)`;
```

So how can I link left side of the dot to progress bar start position? I played a lot with the translate value but I didn't get a success.

Comment: Do you mean your options doesn't work ?

Comment: What do you mean on "center places on the left side of progress bar"? Do you want to slider reversed? E.g the dot should appear on the right side when its value 0?

Comment: do you want it further left or further right?